# CSS media print causes part of the page to be cut off during printing in IE

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-9

I have the following situation, in .NET I have a master page that contains the following CSS for printing:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  div{overflow:visible !important}
</style>
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, however, in IE the top of the page gets cut off. I spent quite a bit of time trying to adjust the page, I know I need `overflow:visible !important` otherwise the page looks terrible in other ways, like the scroll bar appearing. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Did you try setting `margin: 0; padding: 0;`?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell I have now, didn't help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing CSS:

- Make sure all print floats are: `float none;`
- Make sure your **body** is `overflow-y: visible;`
- Make sure all your contents for print have `display: block;`

Comment: Did not include `overflow-y`, but including the other 2 resolved the issue.